# difference between if throws and try

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, try-catch, throw

I have been using Team Tree house along with other methods to learn Java. Well in one of the videos we made a IF statement that used a throw exception. Nothing to crazy. The thing is when I create on it still throws the crazy long message with it. Just to clarify not talking about using a try catch here just using a if to throw a exception. a perfect example is if getting input and want to check if the input is blank or not. if its blank throw a exception to say its blank. Well the message works, I just get the long message with it. So how do I only get my message? I have edited the post to include the code below. The code below is a simple hangman game. Now I fully understand how the try catch method work however, when I use the if statement with a throw exception in my own program it throws the whole ugly message. When on this program it only throws the custom message and if you look you will see its not wrapped in a try catch method.

```
package hangMan;
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class hangMan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What word would you like to guess? ");
        String guessWord = input.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("");
        }

        //create objects for game and prompter class

        Game game = new Game(guessWord);
        Prompter prompter = new Prompter(game);

        while(game.getRemainingTries() > 0 && !game.isWon()){
        prompter.displayProgess();
        prompter.promptForGuess();
        }
        prompter.displayOutcome();
    }

}
```

```
package hangMan;

public class Game {
public static final int MAX_MISSES = 7;
private String answer;
private String hits;
private String misses;

//constructor set answer when created
public Game(String answer){
    this.answer = answer;
    hits = "";
    misses = "";


}

public void setAnswer(String answer){
    this.answer = answer;
}

public boolean applyGuess(String letters){
    if(letters.length()==0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No leter found");
    }
    return applyGuess(letters.charAt(0));
}
private char normalizedGuess(char letter){
    if(! Character.isLetter(letter)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a letter");
    }
    letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
    if(misses.indexOf(letter) != -1 || hits.indexOf(letter)!= -1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You already guessed that letter");

    }

    return letter;
}

public String getAnswer (){
    return answer;
}

//apply guess method get letter to check with answer
public boolean applyGuess(char letter){
    letter = normalizedGuess(letter);
    //checks if letter is in answer
    boolean isHit = answer.indexOf(letter) != -1;
    //if it is store letter if not store letter in misses
    if(isHit){
        hits += letter;
    } else{
        misses += letter;
    }
    //return result hit or not
    return isHit;
}

public int getRemainingTries(){
    return MAX_MISSES - misses.length();
}
public String getCurrentProgress(){
    String progress = "";
    for (char letter : answer.toCharArray()){
        char display = '-';
        if(hits.indexOf(letter) != -1){
            display = letter;
        }
        progress += display;
    }
    return progress;
}

public boolean isWon(){
    return getCurrentProgress().indexOf('-') ==-1;
}

}


package hangMan;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prompter {
    private Game game;

    //constructor
    public Prompter(Game game){
        this.game = game;

    }

    public Prompter(String topic){

    }
    //prompt method to get input and send it to be tested
    public boolean promptForGuess(){
        boolean isHit = false;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isAcceptable = false;

        do{
        System.out.print("Enter a letter:  ");
        String guessInput = scanner.nextLine();

        try{
            isHit = game.applyGuess(guessInput);
            isAcceptable = true;
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
            System.out.printf("%s. Please Try again %n",iae.getMessage());
        }
        } while(! isAcceptable);
        return isHit;
    }

    public void displayOutcome(){
        if(game.isWon()){
            System.out.printf("Congrats you won with %d number of tries remaining!", game.getRemainingTries());
        }else{
            System.out.printf("Bummer the word was %s.  :(", game.getAnswer());
        }
    }

    public void displayProgess(){
        System.out.printf("You have %d remaining tries to guess: %s %n", game.getRemainingTries(), game.getCurrentProgress() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide some relevant snippets of your code.

Comment: You’re letting the exception bubble unhandled all the way up the stack - that causes the stack to unwind and the thread to exit. That is what you’re seeing. You need to, at some point, `catch` and _handle_ the exception.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the message of the exception along with the full stack trace then you'll need to catch the exception with a `try/catch` block and use the *exception variable to only print out the message*. in particular, you're interested in the **`getMessage()`** method of the given exception.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception is different than try catch. They're related. But different.

**Throwing exception** basically means: `intentionally shows an exception (or error) within your code`. *See this definition of 'exception' [here](http://www.careerride.com/Java-exception-defined.aspx).*

Meanwhile, **try-catch** mechanism basically means: `defining what to do when an exception shows up in your code`

---

Look at this code below:

```
public static anImportantFunction(String word) {
    ...
    if(word.length()==0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No letter found");
    }
    ...
}
```

That code means `I want this program to fail/error when the word submitted are empty`. Why would we intentionally make an error in our code!? **So that we could make sure that the program fails due to wrong implementations.** This is different than writing message  in console because writing in console wouldn't actually stop our program.

Comment: Ok so then that means that the if statement that does this throw exception has to refer to a try catch method somewhere in the code then. Because it only shows the custom message. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't loosing my mind. So just to clarify, to avoid the "scary message" lol you need to use the try catch to handle the exception so it doesn't shut the program down correct?

Comment: I didn't really get the first sentence. Sorry, language barrier hehe. But, yep, we can use the try-catch to handle the exception thrown (specifically: to tell what we would do if the exception shows up), so we could avoid things to shut the program down.